# Regex Performance Optimization Tips and Tricks

Tags: regex, performance, optimization

After reading a pretty good [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html) on regex optimization in java I was wondering what are the other good tips for creating fast and efficient regular expressions?

Comment: I would like to mention [Boolean Sequence](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/BooleanSequence) which currently supports less symbols of RE but they are fast and flexible and full of many useful features. You can write your own matchers to add more features or to make them more fast. They also do auto optimization and you can see how they are evaluated using json or json based graphs.

Answer (score 40):

1. Use the non-capturing group `(?:pattern)` when you need to repeat a grouping but don't need to use the captured value that comes from a traditional `(capturing)` group.
2. Use the [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (or non-backtracking subexpression) when applicable `(?>pattern)`.
3. Avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) like the plague by designing your regular expressions to terminate early for non-matches.

I created a video demonstrating these techniques.  I started with the *very* poorly written regular expression in the [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) article `(x+x+)+y`.  And then I made it 3 million times faster after a series of optimizations, benchmarking after every change.   The video is specific to .NET but many of these things apply to most other regex flavors as well:

[.NET Regex Lesson: #5: Optimization](http://regexhero.net/videos/12/optimizing-for-performance)

Answer (score 8):

Use the any (dot) operator sparingly, if you can do it any other way, do it, dot will always bite you...

i'm not sure whether PCRE is NFA and i'm only familiar with PCRE but + and * are usually greedy by default, they will match as much as possible to turn this around use +? and *? to match the least possible, bear these two clauses in mind while writing your regexp.

Answer (score 6):

Know when *not* to use a regular expression -- sometimes a hand coded solution is more efficient and more understandable.

Example: suppose you want to match an integer that's evenly divisible by 3.  It's trivial to design a finite state machine to accomplish this, and therefore a corresponding regex must exist, but writing it out is not so trivial -- and I'd sure hate to have to debug it!

Comment: Yes... but it is trivial in some numeric systems. :-P

Comment: you mean this: `(((0|3|6|9)|((1|4|7)(0|3|6|9)*(2|5|8)))|(((2|5|8)|((1|4|7)(0|3|6|9)*(1|4|7)))((0|3|6|9)|((2|5|8)(0|3|6|9)*(1|4|7)))*((1|4|7)|((2|5|8)(0|3|6|9)*(2|5|8)))))*`? (Yeah, I made a DFA and then GNFA then regex :p)

Comment: Use a fast implementation when you have no backreferences. https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html