# Large string regex replace performance in C#

Tags: c#, regex, performance, replace

I'm facing a problem with Regex performance in C#.

I need to replace on a very large string (270k charachters, don't ask why..). The regex matches about 3k times.

```
private static Regex emptyCSSRulesetRegex = new Regex(@"[^\};\{]+\{\s*\}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);

public string ReplaceEmptyCSSRulesets(string css) {
  return emptyCSSRulesetRegex.Replace(css, string.Empty);
}
```

The string I pass to the method looks something like this:

```
.selector-with-statements{border:none;}.selector-without-statements{}.etc{}
```

Currently the replace process takes up **1500ms** in C#, but when I do exactly the same in Javascript it only takes **100ms**.

The Javascript code I used for timing:

```
console.time('reg replace');
myLargeString.replace(/[^\};\{]+\{\s*\}/g,'');
console.timeEnd('reg replace');
```

I also tried to do the replacing by looping over the matches in reverse order and replace the string in a StringBuilder. That was not helping.

I'm surprised by the performance difference between C# and Javascript in this case, and I think there I'm doing something wrong but I cannot think of anything.

Comment: I think the regex engines used for JS and C# are different.  You should not compare *features* across languages. Am not sure about C# but in Java, creation of regex (when you do `matches()` )itself is a time consuming process. It involves synchronization and other time consuming stuff.

Comment: Try changing the `\s` to `[\f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]` or using `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`. There are differences on how character classes are handled in JS and in C#

Comment: @TheLostMind I agree, but the difference is huge ... So it might be a signal that i'm doing something wrong in C#. I'm trying to find out what exactly.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252194/regex-performance-optimization-tips-and-tricks

Comment: @stribizhev Do you think the regex is the problem? That does not correspond with the javascript regex execution time. But I made a test for only matching without replacing, that was fast in C#.

Comment: @WillemdeWit - I don't see any performance issue with the regex you are using.. I think it is beacuse of the language being used.

Comment: @WillemdeWit: I also do not see any problem with the regex itself. The different platforms not only operate on different regex engines, the strings and string handling are also different.

Comment: Wow! You can get as few as -3,000 matches. That's impressive. I always thought you could only get zero or more matches. Perhaps you mean "approximately 3,000" rather than "plus or minus 3,000"?

Comment: @Enigmativity I changed it, any comments on the real problem?

Comment: May sound stupid, but just in case: same machine?

Comment: @Bolu Yes, same machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really explain the difference of time between Javascript and C#*(*)*. But you can try to improve the performance of your pattern (that produces a lot of backtracking):

```
private static Regex emptyCSSRulesetRegex = new Regex(@"(?<keep>[^};{]+)(?:{\s*}(?<keep>))?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public string ReplaceEmptyCSSRulesets(string css) {
    return emptyCSSRulesetRegex.Replace(css, @"${keep}");
}
```

One of the problems of your original pattern is that when curly brackets are not empty (or not filled with whitespaces), the regex engine will continue to test each positions before the opening curly bracket (with always the same result). Example: with the string `abcd{1234}` your pattern will be tested starting on `a`, then `b` ...

The pattern I suggests will consume `abcd` even if it is not followed by empty curly brackets, so the positions of `bcd` are not tested.

`abcd` is captured in the group named `keep` but when empty curly brackets are found, the capture group is overwritten by an empty capture group.

You can have an idea of the number of steps needed for the two patterns *(check the debugger)*:

[original pattern](https://regex101.com/r/xM9eI8/2)

[new pattern](https://regex101.com/r/xM9eI8/1)

Note: your original pattern can be improved if you enclose `[^}{;]+` in an atomic group. This change will divide the number of steps needed by 2 (compared to the original), but even with that, the number of steps stays high for the previously explained reason.

*(*) it's possible that the javascript regex engine is smart enough to not retry all these positions, but it's only an assumption.*

Comment: Thank you! Your regex seems to work. I will try that in the Javascript regex also

Comment: @WillemdeWit: You can't use the same pattern with javascript since it doesn't support named captures, but you can write something similar using a callback function as replacement: `str.replace(/[^};{]+({\s*})?/g, function (m, g1) { return (g1) ? '' : m; });`

Comment: Turns out that's 10x faster also.

Comment: 10x faster than before? or 10x faster than the previous regex in JS?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Can you please bring the "original pattern" and "new pattern" regex in to the answer - external links are frowned upon as the external site may change and thus break the valuable answer for the SO community. You can certainly have the link **in addition** to showing the regex in the answer.